# Как добавить элемент в массив?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vector

Здравствуйте, друзья! У меня такой вопрос: есть класс в нем я определил вектор с типом string. И я вызываю этот класс с этим массивом и хочу туда передать имя файла, но выводит ошибку о том что массив вышел из границы (vector substript out of range). Как можно этого избежать? Спасибо, заранее
Вот класс:

```
class resqmobject
{
    public:
        string title;
        string uid;
        string description;
        vector <float> floatdata;
        vector <int> intdata;
        vector <SplitReferenses> SRData;
        vector <FaultStruct> FData;
        vector <coord> CoordData;
        vector <float> ZCORN;
        vector <string> FileName;
};
```

А вот так я хочу добавить имя файла в вектор:

```
for (int i = 0; cursor < arr.size(); i++){
    string strFileName = ofn.F_Pillars;
    ofstream fout(ofn.F_Pillars);
    char *c = new char[strFileName.length() + 1];
    FPObject.FileName[i].push_back(*c);
}
```

Comment: Еще раз и медленно...`FPObject.FileName` - вектор строк, `FPObject.FileName[i]` - i-я строка в нем, `FPObject.FileName[i].push_back(*c);` - попытка добавить первый символ из (неинициализированного) массива `c` к i-й строке вашего вектора. Оно-то может добавить (хотя что вы получите?), но у вас, судя по сообщению об ошибке - в `arr` куда больше элементов, чем в `FileName`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы друзья. Пока что разобрался))

Answer (score 1):

Брр...

```
string strFileName = ofn.F_Pillars;
... // Зачем вы тут открываете файл - не знаю, это ваши дела...
FPObject.FileName.push_back(strFileName);
```

И что вы делаете в цикле, мне тоже непонятно (что за `arr` - у вас описания нет). Главное - чтобы добавить в вектор строк строку - вызывайте `push_back()` для этого вектора, передавая ей строку.

Answer (score 0):

не добавляется, выводит ошибку Expression: vector subscript out of range. Как можно от этого избежать и добавить элемент в массив?